# How to set screen size in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7

I am working on Qt and when I am setting the size of widget to W=360 H=640 it is going out of the screen of simulator, Resolution of device is 360*640 but still not showing whole screen.
Is there any other way to fix the content into screen?

Comment: I guess you are trying to develop for symbian device with Qt simulator, you can make application full screen and hide toolbar and statusbar,

Comment: Please provide some code! It could be so many different things...

Answer (score 0):

To adjust widget size correctly on Qt Simulator, remove the condition from the main.cpp file (displayed in the following code snippet) and just leave the w.showMaximized(); line:

```
#if defined(Q_WS_S60)
     w.showMaximized();
 #else
     w.show();
 #endif
```